# Easiest way to call .Net code from classic ASP?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, com, asp-classic

I've been given some legacy ASP code that processes some data and then saves if off to a file system.  I'd like to avoid saving the data to a file and just call my existing .Net code to process it and cut out the middle man.

If I create web service wrapper in .Net, would it be easier to call it from ASP or jQuery?

Comment: Rather than building a web service, why not just post the form fields of the asp page to your asp.net page?

Comment: How in the heck would you call it from jQuery? What does that even mean?

Comment: I've seen code all over for calling a web service using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the asp page to output the results directly the the response stream instead of saving to a file, and then just hit it from your ASP.NET page using `HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse`. That is, invert control to a new asp.net page.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something similar and what I did was create my .NET components and expose them as COM objects and then used them on my ASP pages.

Comment: I knew I should have mentioned it, but I'd like to avoid going the COM route because of the lengthy approval process, etc.

Comment: Lengthy approval process? You are already using COM if you are working with ASP classic code.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973872.aspx) to create a COM wrapper around the .NET code and call it directly? No need for a web service at all.